# How to include conditions in Rx chains?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to switch to another observable if a certain condition is met. Here, if the list is empty, I need to use another  observable:

```
Observable<List<Something>> obs = service.getObservable();
obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .ifTheListIsEmpty(()-> newObservable) // I need something like this
    .subscribe(subscriber)
```

I read about `switchCase` in [this extension](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaComputationExpressions) but I didn't get how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Use flatMap:

```
.flatMap(list ->
     list.isEmpty()
       ? otherObservable
       : Observable.just(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Tassos Bassoukos has a valid answer, another way to do this is:

```
obs.flatMapIterable(l -> l)
   .switchIfEmpty(otherObservable)
```

Depending on your needs, you might consider an `Observable<Something>` that emits multiple `Something`. It allows you to create `obs` using `Observable.from(list)`. You don't even need `flatMapIterable` anymore!

It also makes usage of other operators like `map` much easier since you do not have to operate on the entire list anymore.